# How to find degree on circle is tangent to point outside of circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, point

- I know the (x,y) of a point, P, outside of a circle.
- I know the (x,y) for the origin of a circle, O.
- I know the radius, r, of that circle.

How would I find what degree (e.g. 20 degrees, 270 degrees) is tangent to the point outside of the circle?

[image: click here for an image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Your link is to finding the equation of a tangent line, which i don't understand how it would help.  But you are correct, I should be posting this in math.stackoverflow.  I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry / mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Make origin in circle center (subtract center coordinates from coordinates of point `P`) to simplify calculations

Compose equation system - dot product of tangent and radius-vector is zero, radius vector length is `r`

```
 tx * (tx - px) + ty * (ty - py) = 0
 tx * tx + ty * ty = r*r
```

Solve this system for unknowns `tx, ty` (tangent point)

Get angle as `atan2(ty, tx)`